# Merge two files while keeping lines with a bigger value in a given column awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have two tab delimited files

```
A 500 50
A 600 30
B 300 100
C 600 40
```

and

```
A 500 70
A 600 30
B 300 90
```

and would like to merge the two files, and for the matching lines based in column 1 and 2, I would like to keep the one with a bigger value in column 3.

So that the output would be:

```
A 500 70
A 600 30
B 300 100
C 600 40
```

These are a sample of real values

```
==> cut125_beng_jointvcf_varcal_geno6.txt <==
scaffold_3015                   5910            44.88210969
scaffold_3015                   5912            67.86783682
scaffold_3015                   5916            79.02675660
scaffold_3015                   5926            18.41190163
scaffold_3015                   5930            42.07625795
scaffold_3015                   5931            52.63549142
scaffold_3015                   5954            37.34609103
scaffold_3015                   5983            47.36974946
scaffold_3015                   5991            41.45881125

==> cut125_wbm_jointvcf_varcal_geno6.txt <==
scaffold_3015                   5910            50.79731830
scaffold_3015                   5916            146.20529658
scaffold_3015                   5926            184.50309487
scaffold_3015                   5930            160.27435340
scaffold_3015                   5931            172.71907060
scaffold_3015                   5954            161.39740159
scaffold_3015                   5968            146.54839149
scaffold_3015                   5983            97.01874773
scaffold_3015                   5991            73.54761456
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show what you have tried to solve your problem and tell us where you need help to make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[$1,$2]=$3
   next
}
($1,$2) in a{
   $3=(a[$1,$2]>$3?a[$1,$2]:$3)
   b[$1,$2]
}
1
END{
   for(i in a){
      if(!(i in b)){
        print i,a[i]
      }
   }
}' SUBSEP=" "  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

This will take care of those elements also which are NOT common in both the Input_files too, so if an element is NOT there in Input_file1 and in there Input_file2 it will print it and vice versa too.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                        ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file name Input_file1 is being read.
   a[$1,$2]=$3                  ##Creating array a whose index is $1,$2 and value is $3 of current line.
   next                         ##next is awk out of box keyword to skip all further statements.
}
($1,$2) in a{                   ##Checking conditoin here if Input_file2 $1,$2 of current line is coming in array a then do following.
   $3=(a[$1,$2]>$3?a[$1,$2]:$3)   ##Re-creating $3(3rd column) of current line where if value of a[$1,$2] is greater than $3 than change it to a[$1,$2] else keep it $3.
   b[$1,$2]                     ##Creating an array named b whose index is $1,$2 by this we are keeping track whichever line common in Input_file1 and Input_file2.
}
1                               ##BY mentioning 1 it will print the current line(edited or non-edited by $3).
END{                            ##Starting END block of current awk code here.
   for(i in a){                 ##Starting for loop to traverse through array a.
      if(!(i in b)){            ##Checking if index i is NOT present in array b means un-common lines which did not get print from Input-file1.
        print i,a[i]            ##Printing index i and array a value a[i] here.
      }
   }
}' SUBSEP=" " Input_file1  Input_file2      ##Mentioning SUBSEP value as space and mentioning Input_file1 and Input_file2 here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP output lines should be coming in same order of Input_file2 and Input_file1 then adding following solution then.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                        ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file name Input_file1 is being read.
   a[$1,$2]=$3                  ##Creating array a whose index is $1,$2 and value is $3 of current line.
   if(!b[$1,$2]++){             ##Checking condition here if $1 and $2 is NOT having any index on array b then do following.
     d[++count]=$1 OFS $2}      ##Creating array named d whose index is increasing variable count with value of $1 OFS $2 in it.
   next                         ##next is awk out of box keyword to skip all further statements.
}
($1,$2) in a{                   ##Checking conditoin here if Input_file2 $1,$2 of current line is coming in array a then do following.
   $3=a[$1,$2]>$3?a[$1,$2]:$3   ##Re-creating $3(3rd column) of current line where if value of a[$1,$2] is greater than $3 than change it to a[$1,$2] else keep it $3.
   c[$1,$2]                     ##Creating an array named b whose index is $1,$2 by this we are keeping track whichever line common in Input_file1 and Input_file2.
}
1                               ##BY mentioning 1 it will print the current line(edited or non-edited by $3).
END{                            ##Starting END block of current awk code here.
   for(i=1;i<=count;i++){       ##Starting for loop to traverse through array a.
      if(!(d[i] in c)){         ##Checking if value of array d whose index is i NOT present in array c means un-common lines which did not get print from Input-file1.
        print d[i],a[d[i]]      ##Printing value of array d whose index is i and array a value a[i] here.
      }
   }
}' SUBSEP=" " FilE1  FilE2      ##Mentioning SUBSEP value as space and mentioning Input_file1 and Input_file2 here.
```

Comment: @Ed Morton, sir could you please do let me know if my alignment of code is improved and looking good now sir? will be grateful to you.

Comment: Definitely, the structure is now one that's commonly used across all Algol derivative languages, would be output by any C beautifier, and is very easy to read. Thanks for fixing it and for asking! Now if we could just get you parenthesizing ternary expressions.... :-).

Comment: @EdMorton, cool thanks for feedback, beat for that parenthesis I forget them sometime but started using them to be honest, your guidance always helps, you ROCK.

Comment: I'm not upvoting yet btw because I'm waiting for the OP to add their attempt to their question before I read their question so I've no idea if your script works or not yet as I've no idea what its supposed to do yet!

Comment: @EdMorton, sure, what I believe OP needs to have maximum value out of any files if their 1st and 2nd column matches + I believe non matching lines from both the files too, but true OP could only confirm it.

Comment: I'm just not even going to think about it until I see an effort posted in the question. I have actually noticed you've been much better at parenthesizing ternaries - nice job!

Comment: Cool! How to modify this so that the uncommon lines are printed in the position they show up? And the other question I would have would be whether it is printing the lines that show up in file 1 and not in file 2 and vice verse. Thank you!

Comment: @MadzaYasodaraFariasVirgens, for the line sequence I need to edit code a bit and yes it will show both sides un-common lines either from file1 or file2, give me sometime will try to add order thing in code and post you here then.

Comment: @MadzaYasodaraFariasVirgens, could you please check my EDIT solution it should give you lines in file1 and file2 order itself.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 hummmm still something wrong... I'm pasting a sample of the real files above. Just a sec.

Comment: @MadzaYasodaraFariasVirgens, so it will print like 1st: Matched lines + lines present in file2 and NOT in file1 and at LAST lines which are only present in file1 and NOT in file2, let me know?

Comment: Oh got it. That's fine. I was more thinking of print line in the position they show up when they are read. but this should do it too. Thanks!

Comment: @MadzaYasodaraFariasVirgens, sure cool, keep learning and keep posting on this great site SO.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hey I'm trying to use this code for a tab delimited file by changing SUBSEP=" " to SUBSEP=$"\t ", but it's not working. How should I be doing this? -thanks

Comment: @MadzaYasodaraFariasVirgens, for TAB delimited use `awk -F"\t"` in code considering that your both the files will be tab delimited only.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It does read the 2 tab delimited files but the output is not tab delimited and I need it to be. -thxs-

Comment: add this `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` before `FNR==NR` and see the magic then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Awesome! That works but for some reason it prints repeated lines containing only 1st and 2nd columns in the end of the file. It's like it's printing the index every time it reads it... So that the output has the almost double of lines of the individual inputs, where the second half of then have only two columns.

Comment: @MadzaYasodaraFariasVirgens, can't tell exactly as you haven't mentioned this in your question, try to set `SUBSEP="\t"` too once?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  It works for TAB delimited files using BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} before FNR==NR and setting SUBSEP="\t"! Thanks for the patience!